# How do I update the angle of a Matplotlib.patches.Ellipse object?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ellipse

I'm trying to do a simple animation in python using matplotlib. As part of this I need to be able to animate a patches.Ellipse object. I can move the center location around, but I can't find a way to update or set the angle property of the ellipse. There is a set_center function but no set_angle function, and using update_from(OtherEllipseObject) makes the ellipse dissapear and doesn't seem to help.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as pat
import numpy as np
plt.ion()

xy1 = (1,1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis([0, 5, 0, 5])

ell1 = pat.Ellipse(xy1, 2, 1, 0)
ax.add_patch(ell1)

plt.waitforbuttonpress()
ell1.center = (2,2)
ell1.update_from(pat.Ellipse((2,2),2,1,0))
ax.add_patch(ell1)
plt.waitforbuttonpress()
```

Is there anyway to do this? And if not is there some workaround other than making an ellipse shaped polygon?

Comment: By the way I am using python2.7, matplotlib2.2.4. I have found an uneasy workaround where I just added a set_angle function into the matplotlib patches class that uses the 'stale' property, which I don't really know about, but I have a feeling that this is a heinous crime against good coding practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`matplotlib.patches.Ellipse` has a property `angle`. It should be sufficient to just set it to a different value

```
ell1.angle = 45
```

Comment: I agree that it should be sufficient, and maybe I'm just missing something, but changing the angle property on it's own doesn't update the plot, unlike a similar matlab graphics object.

Comment: well, depending on how you run this, you may need to redraw the figure, eg. `plt.draw()`

Comment: Yeah, that works! Wow, not sure why I never found this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a workaround, but it's not very elegant. Digging through the class definition for the ellipse object I saw that in matplotlib 3.something.something there was a method for setting the center that set self.center to some new value and ALSO set self.stale = True. I'm assuming that stale tells the backend to update the plot, so I just added a method to matplotlib2.2.4 that set angle to a new value and set stale to True. If there's  a better way I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0):

There is a slightly better way as of 3.3.0 with [this PR](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/16395) that adds a proper setter function for the angle:

```
ell1.set_angle(45)
```

See [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Ellipse.html#matplotlib.patches.Ellipse.set_angle), there are now nice getters/setters for all the relevant attributes.